# Is taking adjunction space compatible with topological product?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am reading John W. Milnor, *Morse Theory,* though it might be a bit difficult, and I was showing in Lemma 3.6 that $k\circ l$ is homotopic to identity map. (Until here is for those who have the specified book.) There, I found I have to construct a homotopy $(D^{\lambda}\cup_{\varphi}X)\times [0, 1]\to D^{\lambda}\cup_{\varphi}X$.

In order to define this continuous map, it seems to me that if homeomorphism like $(X\cup_{\varphi}Y)\times Z\approx (X\times Z)\cup_{\varphi\times id_Z}(Y\times Z)
$ holds, then it is easier to define the map because I can make a better use of the universal mapping property. And, this is apparently true according to my intuition. Therefore, I would like to ask if that holds. Any comments appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation means, but in general quotient maps are not respected by products. If $A\to B$ is a quotient map, the induced map $A\times C\to B\times C$ need not be, but if $C$ is locally compact Hausdorff it will be.